# I have a ecommerce Web App but, im having some problem with Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I need to create a custom component only to get the card Information to store it on stripe, and can make a charge to it later.

```
v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element.
              Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.
    at ni (v3:1:319630)
    at e._handleMessage (v3:1:324970)
    at e._handleMessage (v3:1:146061)
    at v3:1:322539
```

This error appears, i checked and the component is mounted, but the way is always mounted, because thats the way stripe works, all the stripe components are in diferents , bring to our app some extra load for nothing but this is another topic.

I need to get rid of this Error.

I have one route with stripe.checkout.sessions.create but, it redirect the user to another tab which is not the behavior i want, I prefer a popup in the same app and get the card data there store it and thats it.

Passing stripe reference in index(for global access)

```
import {Elements} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js";
const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

...others

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <ThemeProvider>
                        <App/>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </Elements>
            </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Stripe CardInput Wrapper(just like doc)
NOTE: I tried this code in an empty project before nesting components and work perfectly.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {CardElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {styled} from "@mui/material/styles";
import {Box, Stack, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import EzLoadingBtn from "../../ezComponents/EzLoadingBtn/EzLoadingBtn";

const CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS = {
    style: {
        base: {
            'color': '#32325d',
            'fontFamily': '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            'fontSmoothing': 'antialiased',
            'fontSize': '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4',
            },
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a',
        },
    },
};

const RootStyle = styled(Stack)(({theme}) => ({
    width: '400px',
    padding: '50px 30px 30px 30px'
}))

export default function CardInput({onSubmit}) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    return (
        <RootStyle>
            <Box component='form' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Stack flexDirection='row' justifyContent='space-between' sx={{marginBottom: '25px'}}>
                    <Typography variant='span'>Card</Typography>
                </Stack>
                <CardElement options={CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS}/>
                <EzLoadingBtn
                    sx={{marginTop: '25px'}}
                    color="inherit"
                    size='large'
                    type='submit'
                    variant='outlined'
                    loading={loading}
                >
                    Save Card
                </EzLoadingBtn>
            </Box>
        </RootStyle>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you share some details of your integration? This error suggests you are unmounting the Element component at some point which you need to resolve. What issues are you having with Checkout? Checkout is meant to be used with a redirect, that's right, the alternative being a custom payment flow. You would not use Checkout & Elements together. More detail of the issue, what you've checked and tried would be helpful.

Comment: I intended to use stripe.paymentIntents.create get the client_secret and charge it in client with stripe.confirmCardPayment. That's the reason I need to store the card as simply as possible to make a charge later.

Answer (score 0):

DONE - The problem was, I used to think that "Wrapping" the App

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
   <ThemeProvider>
      <App/>
   </ThemeProvider>
</Elements>
```

with Elements gonna be enough, but it doesn't.
The Point is that is unnecessary to wrap the whole app with Elements, you just need to wrap the child that is gonna use some stripe component (CardElement, PaymentElement, etc)

```
/*parent*/
<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
    <CardInput/>
</Elements>

/*child*/
export default function CardInput() {
    return (
        <div>
            <PaymentElement/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

With that you are ready to Go.